# Using a node js module in order to read emails from Haraka SMTP server

Tags: node.js, email, npm, haraka

I use **Haraka** (https://github.com/haraka/Haraka), a nodejs SMTP server.

I am looking for ways to read Haraka's received emails using a nodejs solution for that purpose.

I have looked at **mail-listener2** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener2) but it can only read from IMAP.

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mailin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin) looks as a quite usable option.

Comment: It fits my need perfectly. Thanks.